# Behaviour of constructor function return

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this behavior or phenomenon, and what exactly is happening behind the scene?

A constructor function initialized with a new keyword is supposed to return the current object context(this) implicitly.

```js
function User() {
  this.name = "Alice";
}

console.log( new User() );
```

Which is working exactly what it says.

Also explicitly returning an object is also possible with

```js
function User() {
  this.name = "Alice";

  return { name: "Jane" };
}

console.log( new User() );
```

Which explicitly returning object, but when trying to return primitive value it returns what is implicitly supposed to return.

```js
function User() {
  this.name = "Alice";

  return "Jane";
}

console.log( new User() );
```

Thank you in advance. Your efforts will be great input to my knowledge.

Comment: `this` is returned implicitly if the function doesn't return an object. If it does return an object, `new` returns that instead. In your last example, you don't return an object, so it goes back to the default behavior.

Comment: «Usually, constructors do not have a return statement. Their task is to write all necessary stuff into this , and it automatically becomes the result. But if there is a return statement, then the rule is simple: If return is called with an object, then the object is returned instead of this» https://javascript.info/constructor-new#return-from-constructors

Comment: @Barmar then what about primitive values, are they ignored and original object is returned?

Comment: This behaviour is by spec: https://tc39.es/ecma262/2022/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget steps 10.a and 10.b.

What is the question?

Comment: To add to @Barmar's comment: this behaviour is documented in an easy to understand manner [over on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#description) in point 4.

Comment: Yes, primitive values are ignored. Change the last example to `return new String("Jane");` and you'll see the difference.